# Pinboard, NoScript and Firefox

Tags: pinboard

I use Firefox with a pretty un-trusting NoScript setup - basically, most sites stay with disabled Javascript and, if I do grant it, I usually do it only temporarily.

Up until recently, I had no problems on my Mac.  Then my Mac's SSD died, so I put it in repair and browse with Firefox on Windows 10 instead.

Turns out the various Pinboard bookmarklets won't work now unless I enable JS for the site I am visiting.  That's not great - I've whitelisted Pinboard itself, but now NoScript seems to be treating the bookmarklet on the basis of the site I am visiting.  And this behavior now seems to happen on my rebuilt Mac as well.

Basically, if visit www.warez.com for whatever reason, I want to leave that site's JS completely disabled, I don't want to enable it, even temporarily, in order to bookmark it.

Anyone have experience with this on Pinboard?

Or telling NoScript to check against a bookmarklet's original domain (https://pinboard.in/) in this case?

I confess, as much as I appreciate NoScript, I've never understood anything about its advanced Options.

Comment: This is one of those questions that teeter-totters between here and [SU], since some of it may be related to the way the browser handles things  Pinboard is definitely a web application, so I'm comfortable with it staying here for the time being.  Please do not cross-post it, but if it doesn't get an answer here over the next couple of days, you can whittle it down to the browser aspects and repost it there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a bit more looking around (i.e. the **js console**) showed that failure is sometimes not so much due to NoScript as to CSP.

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src https://assets-cdn.github.com”)
```

So, I ended up installing `https://github.com/alexandru/pinboard-popup`, through Firefox extensions and that works than the bookmarklet.  Too bad, I'd rather not add extensions unless I can avoid it.